# VBA ACCESS error 91 object variable or with block variable not set

Tags: vba, ms-access

In a form, when pressing a button called "asignar", I want to insert values to an existing table called "movimientos"

```
Private Sub ASIGNAR_Click()
  Dim db As Database
  Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

  Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("MOVIMIENTOS")
  rs.AddNew
  rs("ESTATUSDOC").Value = "Blah"
  rs("FOLIOFED").Value = "Blah"
  rs("NOMBREDOC").Value = "Blah"
  rs("PREL").Value = "Blah"
  rs("CURP").Value = "Blah"
  rs.Update
End Sub
```

When I press run it keep showing error:

> Error 91 object variable or with block variable not set

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your syntax is a little off, your code should look like this:

```
Private Sub ASIGNAR_Click()

   Dim db As DAO.Database
   Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

   Set db = CurrentDb
   Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("MOVIMIENTOS", dbOpenDynaset, dbAppendOnly)

   rs.AddNew
   rs("ESTATUSDOC").Value = "Blah"
   rs("FOLIOFED").Value = "Blah"
   rs("NOMBREDOC").Value = "Blah"
   rs("PREL").Value = "Blah"
   rs("CURP").Value = "Blah"
   rs.Update

   rs.Close 
   Set rs = Nothing 
   Set db = Nothing

End Sub
```

The issue is primarily the way that you were declaring and setting your `db` variable. I have also adjusted the `OpenRecordset` to match what you are doing.

Comment: All good, though don't forget to close opened recordsets `rs.Close` and clean your memory with `Set rs = Nothing` and `Set db = Nothing`

Comment: @MattHall Thanks for spotting that.

Answer (score 0):

Changing

```
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("MOVIMIENTOS")
```

to

```
Set rs = CurrentDB.OpenRecordset("MOVIMIENTOS")
```

should fix it as well.  You can then lose the `Dim db As Database`