# Run-Time Error '91' VBA Access when Adding record to Table

Tags: sql, database, vba, ms-access

I have a table where I want to add records using the below function.
But when the code executes, it throws Run-Time Error '91'

I've searched all the forums but can't work this out.
Below is my Code:

```
Private Sub CmdCreateLoan_Click()
Dim tempinstal As Integer
Dim tempdate As Date
Dim StrSQL As String
Dim dbs As Database
```

On Error GoTo 0

```
If Me.Loan_Status = 10 Then
MsgBox "Loan Successfully Created", , "Loan Created"
Me.Loan_Status = 9

DoCmd.Save

DoCmd.OpenQuery "que_addinstalment", acViewNormal

tempinstal = Me.No_Instalments - 1
tempdate = DateAdd("m", 1, Me.First_Payment_Date)

Do While tempinstal > 0
Set dbs = CurrentDb

dbs.Execute " INSERT INTO [tblinstalments] " _
    & "(Loan_ID,Instalment_Date,      Total_Instalment,Capital_Instalment,Interest_Instalment,Next_Balance) VALUES " _
    & "('loan_ID','tempdate','instalment','Capital_Instalment','interest_instalment','next_Balance');"

dbs.Close
Set dbs = Nothing


tempinstal = tempinstal - 1
tempdate = DateAdd("m", 1, tempdate)
Loop

DoCmd.Close

Else

MsgBox "Loan Contract not Printed. Please Print before proceeding", , "Print  Loan Contract"

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Its happening on this: dbs.Execute " INSERT INTO [tblinstalments] " _ & "(Loan_ID,Instalment_Date, Total_Instalment,Capital_Instalment,Interest_Instalment,Next_Balance) VALUES " _ & "('loan_ID','tempdate','instalment','Capital_Instalment','interest_instalment','next_Balance');"

Comment: You have to `Set dbs` to your database object first.

Comment: Set `dbs = CurrentDb()`

Comment: check this link for related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31274060/vba-access-error-91-object-variable-or-with-block-variable-not-se

Comment: Tom - I did Set dbs = CurrentDb

Comment: Abdul - I added the brackets - same error

Comment: I cant see why `loan_ID` and `Instalment_date` are string fields?... and why you want to insert a record that just has the name of the columns?

Comment: @user6522953 It would be helpful if you showed us some of your data.

Comment: Abdul - Thanks so much - Changed the code from thsi link :  
check this link for related stackoverflow.com/questions/31274060/

Comment: Working Perfectly - Thanks all for your help!